# How to analyse the keyword density of an entire website?

Tags: seo, keywords

My competitor has a forum where its customer post. I want to use all those threads to determine which keywords I should use on my own site, because forums have terms customers use and search for.

I can pick a page and analyse it to find which keyword and phrase are popular, but how do I analyse the whole site ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this the other day which seemed blinding for a free tool although I haven't had any time to install and get to grips with;

http://www.link-assistant.com/website-auditor/features.html

Answer (score 1):

If your competitor's site has a feed, you can try out [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net).

Wordle can take the URL of any blog, blog feed, or any other web page that has an Atom or RSS feed & build a word cloud which gives greater prominence to words that appear more frequently in the source text.

It may not be comprehensive but it's still useful.